# React native can store fingerprint data for our own app?

Tags: react-native, authentication, bioinformatics, fingerprint

can we store fingerprint data for over own app through and verify, add new data over app through ,also removing and updating.
so can we use any third party SDKs or Library provided and manage fingerPrint data manage.and can we store fingerprint mobile fingerprint though and manage over fingerprint data?

Comment: you may use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-biometrics

Comment: Hello @NensiKasundra react-native-biometrics npm Package only verify fingerprint in over Device inside available. we create some security related app, so we need to store personal fingerprint data in own Database ,so is it possible any third party api or SDKs through

Comment: you may use the result-based approach using react-native-biometrics https://blog.nviso.eu/2021/04/06/a-closer-look-at-the-security-of-react-native-biometric-libraries/

Comment: Hello @NensiKasundra we need to store fingerprint data personal database like use login multiple device so user login multiple device through using fingerprint use  phone Touch(Scanner) instead any Biometrics Device(not use) like https://www.aware.com/fingerprint-recognition but they did't accept demo request,any third party api or sdks available plz Dame me.